# What does the <primitive: xyz> statement do in a method declaration?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Here's the `asciiValue` method of the `Character` class:

```
asciiValue
   <primitive: 171>
   ^ self primitiveFailed
```

asciiValue is sent to a character object, for example $A, and returns its ascii code. Can someone explain how does the `asciiValue` method work? where does that `<primitive: 171>` comes from and what its purpose?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321776/smalltalk-how-primitives-are-implemented help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this is a primitive rather than a regular Smalltalk method is that `Characters` in Pharo are *immediate* objects.

When seen in memory, objects are data structures with a header and some additional fields, one for each of the instance variables. Those slots contain pointers to the objects currently bound to the ivars.

In the case of `SmallIntegers`, however, this structure was traditionally simplified in that an object having an ivar that is a `SmallInteger` does not point to the small integer object, it has the `SmallInteger`. This is why `SmallIntegers` are called immediate objects: you don't point to them, you have them.

Of course, to implement immediate values you need a way to distinguish them in memory. `SmallIntegers` are integers but in memory pointers are integers too. The trick to establish the distinction is to observe that all objects are allocated in addresses that are multiple of 4 (32 bits) or 8 (64 bits). This means that pointers always have their two lower bits equal to 0. Thus, you can use these spare bits to *tag* immediate objects and store the immediate value in the remaining higher bits.

In the case of Pharo and other dialects, `Characters` whose code point fits within a byte, can be easily tagged so they become immediate. This is why `Characters` (and `SmallIntegers`) have no ivars: they are the value they represent, plus some tag for the Virtual Machine to tell the difference.

In consequence, the Smalltalk image has no way to access the numeric value of an ASCII `Character`, and needs to ask the VM to read it instead. This is why Pharo needs a primitive to answer the `#asciiValue` message.

For more information on primitives in Smalltalk take a look at [Smalltalk: How primitives are implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321776/smalltalk-how-primitives-are-implemented).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.